# Find the points on the surface $xy^2z^4=14$ that are closest to the origin.

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Find the points on the surface $x y^2 z^4=14$ that are closest to the origin.

this was my exam question. Our teacher said she wont publish answers. I couldn't even move my pen with this question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Refer to the Lagrange multiplier method; you are to find the min value of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ under the constraint $xy^2 z^4 - 14 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The distance is

\begin{align}
& (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}\\
=& \left(x^2+2(\frac12y^2)+4(\frac14z^2)\right)^{1/2}\\
\ge &7 \left( \frac{x^2y^4z^8}{2^2\cdot 4^4}\right)^{1/{14} }
= \frac{7^{9/14}}{2^{4/7} }
\end{align}
where the AM-GM inequality is applied and the equality, or the minimum distance, occurs at $x^2=\frac{y^2}2= \frac{z^2}4$, which leads to the closest points $x=(\frac7{16})^{1/7}$, $y= \pm \sqrt2(\frac7{16})^{1/7} $ and $z= \pm 2(\frac7{16})^{1/7} $.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The function which you have to minimize is $d(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, but there is a side condition (or a constraint): $xy^2z^4=14 \iff xy^2z^4-14=0 \quad (\varphi(x,y,z)=0)$.

Hence, compose Lagrange function $F(x,y,z,\lambda)=d(x,y,z)-\lambda\varphi(x,y,z)$, the extreme value of $F$ will be an extreme value also for $d$.